# Most efficient way to retrieve data from two lists nested as values of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, coordinates, euclidean-distance

I have a dictionary of coordinates from structures in three dimensional space with

```
    struc_dict = { 
    'struc1' : [np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), ...],
    'struc2' : [np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), ...], 
    'struc3' : [np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), ...], 
    'struc4' : [np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), np.array(x,y,z), ...] }
```

As an example:

```
struc_dict = { 
    'struc1' : [[-31.447,  -4.428, -28.285], [-32.558,  -2.108, -29.213], [-31.656,  -4.071, -30.89 ], [-33.899,  -4.504, -29.349]],
    'struc2' : [[-27.487, -15.05,  -31.418], [-29.178, -14.63,  -33.498], [-29.548, -16.754, -31.937], [-30.028, -14.278, -30.977]], 
    'struc3' : [[-16.07,   -2.042, -29.853], [-16.734,  -4.162, -29.905], [-16.279,  -4.438, -28.936], [-16.544,  -4.098, -31.514]]}
```

And I would like to find out the shortest distance between each of the structures.
So I would like to go through the dictionary, grab a pair of values and calculate the shortest distance.

My current code looks like that, but it's not very pretty or efficient:

```
import numpy as np
for s1 in struc_dict.keys():
    for s2 in struc_dict.keys():
        # only consider distances between two structures
        if s1 == s2:
            continue
        else:
            # defining an arbitrary max value, necessary for the first comparison?
            min_dist = 10000
            for c1 in struc_dict[s1]:
                for c2 in struc_dict[s2]:
                    # calculates the distance between the two coordinates
                    if np.linalg.norm(np.array(c1)-np.array(c2)) <= min_dist:
                        min_dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array(c1)-np.array(c2))

            print("Min dist between {s1} & {s2} : {min:.3f} units".format(s1=s1, s2=s2, min=min_dist))
```

Output for the example:

```
Min dist between struc1 & struc2 : 10.309 units
Min dist between struc1 & struc3 : 14.804 units
Min dist between struc2 & struc1 : 10.309 units
Min dist between struc2 & struc3 : 15.377 units
Min dist between struc3 & struc1 : 14.804 units
Min dist between struc3 & struc2 : 15.377 units
```

This code works, but calculates the distances between two structures two times, since it has to go through the dictionary twice. Also, I need a large min_dist start value for the first comparison for each two structures, but it there a way around that?

In general, there must be a more elegant solution for that. Thanks!

Comment: There propably is. Why dont you prepare a [mre] with a prefilled list of say 12-20 points in the structure you have and provide that - possibly someone might tackle the task then.

Answer (score 1):

As for more *elegant* solution consider [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Consider following simple example:

```
import itertools
points = {'A': (1,1), 'B': (2,2), 'C': (3,3)}
def dist(a, b):
    return ((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)**0.5
for p1, p2 in itertools.product(points.keys(), repeat=2):
    print('Distance between',p1,'and',p2,'is',dist(points[p1],points[p2]))
```

Output:

```
Distance between A and A is 0.0
Distance between A and B is 1.4142135623730951
Distance between A and C is 2.8284271247461903
Distance between B and A is 1.4142135623730951
Distance between B and B is 0.0
Distance between B and C is 1.4142135623730951
Distance between C and A is 2.8284271247461903
Distance between C and B is 1.4142135623730951
Distance between C and C is 0.0
```

This allows to avoid one nesting level, as opposed to `for` inside `for`.

Answer (score 0):

From your first post it was not clear whether the number of coordinates is the same across structures, so I assumed it was not.

Here is a slightly revised version of your naive approach and a first improved version exploiting the fast low-level vectorization of NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np

def naive(data):
  res = np.inf
  for k1, v1 in data.items():
    for k2, v2 in data.items():
      if k1 == k2:
        continue
      for c1 in v1:
        for c2 in v2:
          res = np.minimum(res, np.sum((c1 - c2)**2))
  return np.sqrt(res)

def version1(data):
  res = np.inf
  for k1, v1 in data.items():
    for k2, v2 in data.items():
      if k1 == k2:
        continue
      res = np.minimum(res, np.min(np.sum((v1[None, ...] - v2[:, None, :])**2, axis=-1)))
  return np.sqrt(res)
```

The crucial point is `v1[None, ...] - v2[:, None, :]` where, by adding an additional axis to each structure in a different location, we exploit the NumPy broadcasting to remove the two inner loops.

Testing on your data (needs IPython, just to use the simplified interface to `timeit`):

```py
struc_dict = { 
    'struc1' : [[-31.447,  -4.428, -28.285], [-32.558,  -2.108, -29.213], [-31.656,  -4.071, -30.89 ], [-33.899,  -4.504, -29.349]],
    'struc2' : [[-27.487, -15.05,  -31.418], [-29.178, -14.63,  -33.498], [-29.548, -16.754, -31.937], [-30.028, -14.278, -30.977]], 
    'struc3' : [[-16.07,   -2.042, -29.853], [-16.734,  -4.162, -29.905], [-16.279,  -4.438, -28.936], [-16.544,  -4.098, -31.514]]}
data = {k: np.array(v) for k,v in struc_dict.items()}
%timeit naive(data)
%timeit version1(data)
```

Output:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 433 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.7 µs per loop
```

To better assess performance, let's try with more data:

```
np.random.seed(42)

for n in [10, 20, 50, 100]:
  for max_size in [10, 20, 50, 100]:
    data = {str(i): np.random.normal(size=[np.random.randint(1, max_size), 3])
            for i in range(n)}
    print("Measuring for n=%r and max_size=%r" % (n, max_size))
    %timeit naive(data)
    %timeit version1(data)
```

Output:

```
Measuring for n=10 and max_size=10
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 784 µs per loop
Measuring for n=10 and max_size=20
10 loops, best of 3: 32.5 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 894 µs per loop
Measuring for n=10 and max_size=50
1 loop, best of 3: 323 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.94 ms per loop
Measuring for n=10 and max_size=100
1 loop, best of 3: 478 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
Measuring for n=20 and max_size=10
10 loops, best of 3: 43.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 ms per loop
Measuring for n=20 and max_size=20
10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.78 ms per loop
Measuring for n=20 and max_size=50
1 loop, best of 3: 1.41 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop
Measuring for n=20 and max_size=100
1 loop, best of 3: 4.34 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
Measuring for n=50 and max_size=10
1 loop, best of 3: 341 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
Measuring for n=50 and max_size=20
1 loop, best of 3: 1.24 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.3 ms per loop
Measuring for n=50 and max_size=50
1 loop, best of 3: 7.86 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 45.9 ms per loop
Measuring for n=50 and max_size=100
1 loop, best of 3: 22.6 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 97.1 ms per loop
Measuring for n=100 and max_size=10
1 loop, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 83.5 ms per loop
Measuring for n=100 and max_size=20
1 loop, best of 3: 4 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 96.1 ms per loop
Measuring for n=100 and max_size=50
1 loop, best of 3: 27.4 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 180 ms per loop
Measuring for n=100 and max_size=100
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 50s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 447 ms per loop
```

Speed up varies a lot in function of number of coordinates (the more the better, as long as your machine have enough free RAM).

Further improvements can be achieved by:

1. Using `np.einsum` (Einstein summation) instead of `np.sum`, which is well known to be faster
2. If all the structures have the same number of coordinates you can remove the other two loops by building two four-dimensional arrays (e.g. Nx1xMx3 and 1xNxMx3, where N is the number of structures and M is the number of coordinates for each).
3. Combine both the previous points!